# How to quote in sinatra/rails app code snippet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sinatra, code-snippets

I'm trying to write in sinatra the blog app. I want to quote in my post code snippet. How to add a gems like: CodeSnippets or Snippet or another to make it work? Do you know of any good examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really hard to understand, but if you are asking for a gem to highlight source code, have a look at Ultraviolet:

http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Ok, I mean about highlight source code. Now remains to learn how to use it with Sinatra.

Comment: @luzny Why would you tag the question with ruby-on-rails if it's a Sinatra question?